# Python pyautogui hotkey with variable - works without like ('ctrl','a')

Tags: pyautogui

When i run:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','a')
```

it works fine.

But when i put the string in a variable it doesn't work:

```
my_var = "'ctrl','a'"    
pyautogui.hotkey(my_var)
```

my_var is a string object, python do not trow an error, but nothing happens.

If I try with a list objekt like, dosen't work:

```
pyautogui.hotkey(list(my_var))
```

I can do:

```
print(my_var)
```

And I get back: 
    'ctrl','a'

I can make pyatogui.press(tab) work from a variable.

I have tryed some kind of raw string:

```
my_var = r"'ctrl','a'"
```

without any succes.

In PyCarm the comma is orange (probably a list of arguments), and green when string is put in a variable.

I upload an image of my example code:

[image]

And the complete code for anyone to try (maybe I should warn that it when it works press ctrl+a, witch in most programs are select all):

```
import time
import pyautogui

time.sleep(3)

# This part works
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','a')

# This part do not work, no error
my_var = "'ctrl','a'"
pyautogui.hotkey(my_var)
```

I run Windows10 and python 3.7 and PyCharm.

Answer (score 4):

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','a')
enter code here
```

Pases 2 arguments to the function

But when you use this:

```
my_var = "'ctrl','a'"    
pyautogui.hotkey(my_var)
```

You pases just 1 argument to the function which doses not work in this case

You can use:

```
my_var = ['ctrl','a']
pyautogui.hotkey(my_var[0],myvar[1])
```

or

```
my_var = {”first”:'ctrl',”second”:'a'}
pyautogui.hotkey(my_var[”first”],myvar[”second”])
```

Comment: Thanks yes good ide, but I think i kind of tried the 3:e case and a then only got qutationmark back and as second argument i got the "c" in ctrl back. I tried doing a my_var.split(",") but then it was a list and the pyautogui.hotkey trow an error. I agree with you that it seems that they should be different arguments for the function. It feels like basic stuff in pyautogui, but it seems tricky, thanks any way all help apriciated. :)

Comment: This is because you didn’t modified ` my_var ` when you use ` my_var[0] `  you get the first element of ` my_var ` wich is `“ctrl ” ` if  `my_var ` is an list. and `‘ ` if ` my_var `  is a string: the first element of the `"'ctrl','a'"` is `‘ `

Answer (score 1):

Thanks rafalou38 for giving me some feedback, I been trying this for 2 h.
Your ide actually works for this special case if we first do a split, and then add the str() funktion to the seperate list elements, I did it with the pluss sign insted as below:

```
my_var = "ctrl+a"
my_var = my_var.split('+')
pyautogui.hotkey(str(my_var[0]),str(my_var[1]))
```

This will be good enough for all cases with 2 arguments, and I could easy hardcode a case for 3 as well with:

```
len(my_var)
```

will give me how many elements it has, there could be some cases with 3 or even 4 but then very unlikly above that. Thanks a lot for the input. Great now I can go to bed, thinking this can be fixed for all likly cases.

I tried this for making a new folder witch is of order 3, and it worked out on first try:

```
my_var = "ctrl+shift+n"
my_var = my_var.split('+')
pyautogui.hotkey(str(my_var[0]),str(my_var[1]),str(my_var[2]))
```

:)

Comment: Can you validate my answer if it works and upvote it please :)